# Trying to use value from updated row in a where statement in my trigger

Tags: mysql

I want to use a trigger to automatically update another table but I'm having some problems with it.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trigger1` $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger1`
AFTER UPDATE ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW

UPDATE `table4`

inner join (SELECT o.`Name`, 
       o.Date,
       (o.`Availability` * (c.Rate)) total

  FROM `table2` o

  LEFT JOIN `table1` r
            ON o.`Name` = r.`Name`
           AND o.Date = r.Date

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT table3.`Name`,Choke, Rate FROM table3
left join `table1` as w

          on table3.`Name` = w.`Name` 
          and table3.Choke = w.`Size`

where w.`Name` = table3.`Name`

and table3.Date <= w.Date

ORDER BY table3.Date DESC
LIMIT 1) c

ON c.`Name` = o.`Name`)x

set `Contribution` = x.total

where (`table4`.Date) = x.Date and `table4`.`Name` = x.`Name`;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I would like to use the date from table1 row (that is the table which triggers the trigger) in my left join named c. As it stands `c.Rate` gives the same value every time because it uses the default table1.

If the row being updated has a date of '2022-01-13' then I want the date used at the line asterisked

```
and table3.Date <= w.Date
```

I want `w.Date` to be '2022-01-13'. But as it stands I can't get that and all the `c.Rate` give the same value.

Thanks.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I admit I haven't been paying attention to good coding standard. Will try to adhere to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of consistent indentation and capitalisation makes your query almost impossible to read.  Instead of obfuscating what is going on by using `table1`, `table2`, `table3` & `table4` you would be better off using the real table names, as it will make more sense to anyone trying to read it.

Your current update query makes little sense with the repeated left joins back to the originating `table1` but it is hard to be sure given the lack of supporting information in your question.  Your first left join to `table1`, aliased as `r`, does not get used anywhere.  Your second left join to `table1`, aliased as `w`, is then referenced in the where clause which turns it into an inner join.

I suggest you update your question with the CREATE TABLE statements and some sample data to show the values before and after executing your update and the trigger update.  Your current update query is definitely not the most efficient way of achieving your goal.

I don't really understand your question but it seems that you all are asking is how to use the value from the `table1` row being updated?  In which case the answer is simply -

```sql
        and w.Date = NEW.Date
```

where `NEW` references the post-update version of the `table1` row.

From [25.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) -

> Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access
> columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL
> extensions to triggers; they are not case-sensitive.
>
> In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old
> row. In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; there is no
> new row. In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to
> the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to
> the columns of the row after it is updated.